# Neural Networks on a High Dimensional Data

Tags: neural-network, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset from the UCI repository(gene expression cancer RNA-Seq Data Set; Link:- https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/gene+expression+cancer+RNA-Seq#). This dataset has 801 instances and 20531 attributes. Since the data is high dimensional(read:- 20531), what techniques would be ideal for classification? Would the approach of using Principal Component Analysis for reducing the dimensions, followed by Multi-Layer Perceptron be good enough for this problem?

Comment: Your question is concerned with theoretical aspects of machine learning. You would be better (and should) ask these kind of questions on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sure. Thanks a ton.